# One event trigger one class and one id jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

From the same click, I need to add two different values in two different fields: value and value*50. So, I'm trying to get one field by the class and the other by the ID. For some reason, it's not working. Here is the logic I'm using. Could someone enlighten me?

```js
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('button').on('click', function() {
  let value = this.value;
  $($(this).data('target')).val(value*50).trigger('input');
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
  let value = this.value;
  $($(this).attr('id')).val(value).trigger('input');
});


</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="bedroom" data-target=".i1" value="1">1</button>
 <input type="text" class="i1" id="i1" name="i1"><br>
 <input type="text" id="bedroom">
```

Comment: You cant have multiple elements with the same id, Id's must be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID. Also you don't need to write 2 click events for the same button.

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  let value = this.value;
  $($(this).data('target')).val(value * 50).trigger('input');
  $("." + $(this).attr('id')).val(value).trigger('input');
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  let value = this.value;
  $($(this).data('target')).val(value * 50).trigger('input');
  $("." + $(this).attr('id')).val(value).trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="bedroom" data-target=".i1" value="1">1</button>
<input type="text" class="i1" id="i1" name="i1"><br>
<input type="text" class="bedroom">
```

Comment: Nice! You concatenate the "." with the element name. I didn't know it is possible.